# What is the correct way to pass data from MTA to STA in COM and vise versa

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, com, ipc

I have a multhithreaded application which works sitting in MTA. It performs calls of outproc object (let's name it OUTPROC_OBJ_A) and everything works fine:
each thread calls CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED).

But now, I have yet another couple of com objects sitting in a dll - I need to use it in my application. Lets name one of it INPROC_OBJ_B. Their threading model is apartment threading. Also, it shares interfaces from OUTPROC_OBJ_A (it uses some of data as arguments of methods importing it from .tlb file)

When I do something like this (in one thread):

```
idl 1:
interface IData : IDispatch
{
}

coclass ConcreteData : IData;

idl 2: (uses idl 1):
interface IOBJ_B : IDispatch
{
    void initData([in, out] IData* data);
}

coclass INPROC_OBJ_B : IOBJ_B;

main:
{

    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    ...

    {
        // 1.) Create instance of INPROC_OBJ_B.
        CComPtr<IOBJ_B> pOBJ_B = CreateInstance(INPROC_OBJ_B);
        // 2.) Pass to some method of INPROC_OBJ_B some data (For example, pointer to another com object created here.)
        CComPtr<IData> pData = CreateInstance(ConcreteData);

        pOBJ_B->initData(pData);

        // 3.) Here it crashes. Probably on release of pData. 
        // initData now is empty and does nothing.
    }

    CoUninitialize();
}
```

When I do this, it can work fine sometimes. But sometimes, it crashes the entire application with access violation. Sometimes it throws object_is_not_connected_exception.

When I replace COINIT_MULTITHREADED with COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED in CoInitializeEx, it works fine. But I can't do this in my application - The entire infrastructure is in MTA.

[UPDATE] : more pseudo code in example.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "The entire infrastructure is in MTA" is just another way of saying "we don't *have* an infrastructure".  That's not a good place to be when you start using somebody else's code, thread-safety is a very elusive goal in general and forever lacking in 3rd party code.  The mishaps you describe are exactly backwards, it should behave very poorly when you lie with COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED.  If you use MTA instead then COM will create a thread to give the object a safe home.  Do make sure that you see this thread getting created with the debugger.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Actually, I see the same behaviour even if I create  a test application from scratch which just goes into MTA, creates there INPROC_OBJ_B and calls its method. If I do so, I see undefined behavior. If I change COINIT_MULTITHREADED  to COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED , it works fine. I have only one thread in this application (main thread)

Comment: Properly written code (implementation of INPROC_OBJ_B) will work fine with both STA and MTA instantiating thread. So you have a bug there and question description has no mention of it or crash point. My guess would be that INPROC_OBJ_B instantiation is non-COM, taking place without marshaling or otherwise breaking marshaling. That is, the bug is there but it's elsewhere, not in the details you mentioned.

Comment: `[in, out] IData*` This can't be. Either the parameter is `[in]`, or its type is `IData**` Apart from that, there's nothing wrong in (what little) code you've shown. The problem most likely lies in the code you haven't.

Comment: Thanks!
The strange thing is when I remove call of a method initData it works fine as well.

Comment: Beside the incorrect [in,out] annotation that Igor mentioned, if we suppose it's [in] in fact, then you must understand that, in the initData method, you're passing a COM interface reference. If object B is using it before it's itself release, then it should do an AddRef on it, for example if it keeps an internal reference on it, otherwise when your code release pData, then the memory allocated behind the passed-in reference to B may disappear (and cause an access violation). You really need to understand a bit more of COM if you want to do multithreading/ipc COM in C++...

Comment: Normally one would use `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream` to exchange stuff between incompatible apartments.  _[The CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream function enables an object to easily and reliably marshal an interface pointer to another thread in the same process. The stream returned in the ppStm parameter is guaranteed to behave correctly when a client running in the receiving thread attempts to unmarshal the pointer. The client can then call the CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream to unmarshal the interface pointer and release the stream object](http://tinyurl.com/o3x9v4z)_.